# Append Content-Encoding header to specific file in IIS 7.5

Tags: javascript, iis-7, http-headers, gzip

I want to server a file.gz.js GZIP compressed file from my IIS server. I keep the postfix as ".js" so IIS will serve the file with Javascript header. However, I want to append "Content-Encoding" header that equals to "gzip", so the browser will know to decompress it. How can I add a "Content-Encoding" header to a specific file?

Second, can I just rename the Javascript file with .gz extension and it will be the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IIS 6, click on the website that contains the file, in the right hand pane right click on the specific file go to "Properties", go to the "Http Headers" tab, and add a customer header with a name of "Content-Encoding" and a value of "gzip".

In IIS 7, this is possible from the GUI, and I believe you can do it from the web.config of an asp.net application. However I don't have access to IIS 7 right now so I can't give you step by step directions.  You can probably click the website, then click the Content tab at the bottom, then right click the specific file.  Find some menu similar to properties, and find somewhere it allows you to add customer headers.

Sorry, thats the best I can give for IIS 7 at the moment.

There are of course other solutions with custom http handlers, but this isn't advisable.

Answer (score 0):

In newer versions of IIS you can still do this through the GUI but it's a bit more fiddly:

- In the left-hand pane, expand the site and click on the folder where the file is located.
- Switch to "Content View" (at the bottom of the main pane)
- Click the specific file
- Click "Switch to features view" in the Actions pane (right hand side)
- Click on the "HTTP Response Headers" feature

Now you can edit the response headers for that specific file only.